# Each type of import module have a error

Tags: python, import, module

I have the two lines code:

```
import  ui.interface.interface
obj = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
```

I have same code in another package and work fine. but i get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from materials.materials import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/materials/materials.py", line
40, in <module>
    from  ui.interface.interface import *  
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/interface/interface.py",
line 32, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFrame.py", line
24, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFindFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFindFrame.py",
line 14, in <module>
    from common.objects.objects import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/common/objects/objects.py",
line 28, in <module>
    obj = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'interface'
```

When i changed the my code to:

```
from  ui.interface.interface import *
obj = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
```

I get the :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from materials.materials import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/materials/materials.py", line
40, in <module>
    from  ui.interface.interface import *  
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/interface/interface.py",
line 32, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFrame.py", line
24, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFindFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFindFrame.py",
line 14, in <module>
    from common.objects.objects import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/common/objects/objects.py",
line 28, in <module>
    Obj = ui.interface.interface.InterfaceCodes()
NameError: name 'ui' is not defined
```

Also if i delete "ui.interface.interface" i get the :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 31, in <module>
    from materials.materials import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/materials/materials.py", line
40, in <module>
    from  ui.interface.interface import *  
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/interface/interface.py",
line 32, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFrame.py", line
24, in <module>
    from ui.materialsFindFrame import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/ui/materialsFindFrame.py",
line 14, in <module>
    from common.objects.objects import *
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/common/objects/objects.py",
line 28, in <module>
    Obj = InterfaceCodes()
NameError: name 'InterfaceCodes' is not defined
```

**My ask** is , really i don't know how to do...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a circular import problem. By the look of your first stack trace,

- `ui.interface.interface` imports `ui.materialsFrame`,
- `ui.materialsFrame` imports `ui.materialsFindFrame`,
- `ui.materialsFindFrame` imports `common.objects.objects`,
- `common.objects.objects` imports `ui.interface.interface`,

... which is already in the process of importing. Since `ui.interface.interface` tried to import `ui.materialsFrame` right at the start, at the moment of the last import it does not yet have `InterfaceCodes` in its variables, that's why you get `AttributeError`.

Try to redesign your library to get rid of this loop, or at least try not to actually call functions/constructors at import time.

Comment: I think `python` solved this problem and just `C/C++` have this problem in `include files`.Thank you...!

Comment: Do you have any other solution without changing arch?

Comment: As I said in the last phrase, if you only define classes and functions at the root level, a circular import is not a problem, because the names inside functions/methods will be resolved at runtime, not at import time. You can't really get more than that in any language.